# Unmount NFS server

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

I got a client which is mounted on a NFS server. Now when the server restarts
it gets a new ip addr. So in order to reconnect the client I first
unmount (unmount -f/mnt/billing) the NFS and then I try to mount it again. 
But the client does not allow me to do so
it says:
device is busy.

I tried unmount -l, it works in the cosole,
but not in the script.

Your advice would be helpful.

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 2):

Check with fuser or lsof which process is still accessing the NFS share, then kill it.

As a last resort, umount -f should also let you unmount the NFS share.

Comment: ty for the answer, i will try asap :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you still in same nfs mounted dir? This is most common mistake, change the dir and umount again. If that is not the case then try

> fuser /mnt/share

kill the process id that you get and do umount

Comment: You may want to use the -c option on the directory to show all open files in said directory.